# Is It Rude to Award Only Half Bounty through Inactivity?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

I have a question that is coming up for bounty in about one hour: [Using the Y Combinator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819718/using-the-y-combinator-in-c-sharp).

However, I don't quite like the only answer (which happens to have 4 upvotes) enough to mark it as *the* answer and award the bounty.

Since it is the only answer (and thus the highest-voted one), and [has at least a score of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), it is going to get half the bounty amount (25 rep) if I take no action.

As I commented on the answer, it only answers one of my questions and even states that it ignores the other two, so I don't consider it good enough to be the accepted answer.

At this point, would it be considered rude *not* to award the full bounty (even if I don't mark it as the answer)?

Comment: That's why you should refrain from posting more than one question per post. Had you done so, there would be no problem here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi They are all related, and had I asked it as three separate questions, 75% of their text would be the same.

Comment: That answer is not eligible for automatic awarding because it wasn't posted during the bounty period.

Comment: You could add a comment (not a question addendum please - commentary about questions doesn't really belong in questions) explaining why you are not awarding it. I think it's OK to not award it.

Comment: I mean you can add a note in the comments under the Stack Overflow question you're referring to.

Comment: Oops, I just read your response to one of the answers: "I would be much happier about upvoting/marking as answer/awarding bounty if you answered more than just part 1 of my question. At this point, it seems you are going to receive half the bounty, but I'm sure you can do better". You may not be a native English speaker, but that sounds _extremely_ ungrateful. I suggest you reword that!

Comment: (No, there's no need to comment on a question and the answer).

Comment: @halfer I'm not sure what my English skills have to do with this... (and I am a native English speaker. I notice no errors in grammar or spelling in my comment.) And how is it ungrateful? I state what exactly I want and the reward I would give.

Comment: @halfer It doesn't sound ungrateful to me at all.

Comment: nice question! hope you get a full answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not rude or inappropriate to not award a bounty to an answer that you don't feel has earned it.  It's your bounty, you're free to award, or not award, it to whatever answer you want.

Whether others (or even you) have upvoted some of the answers answers has no bearing on this.

Comment: The OP doesn't have the freedom to withhold the bounty entirely though.

Comment: @BoltClock which is a pity..

Comment: @BoltClock The question he asked was whether its wrong to let the bounty auto award instead of manually awarding the bounty to the answer it would be given to, given that the auto award results in only half the bounty.  Given that he already explained all of that in the question, I see no need to repeat it all in the answer.

Comment: That does make sense.